# Issue with getting divs to overlap and position fixed

Tags: html, css, position

I'm looking on Cnet's homepage and attempting to duplicate their over-lapping slide-down layer. 
[Click to see their homepage](http://www.cnet.com/)

[image]

How exactly is this done? I know it has to do with the middle layer being positioned fixed and then `z-index` and a high `margin-top` between layers, I just can't figure it out.

Any ideas?

```css
#blue, #green, #red {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
#blue {
  background: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}
#green {
  background: green;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 200px;
}
#red {
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="blue"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
<div id="red"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

Set `position` to other than `static` on your non fixed div's for `z-index` to work properly.

```css
htmlk, body {
  margin: 0;
}
#blue, #green, #red {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
#blue {
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 2;
}
#green {
  background: green;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 50px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
#red {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="blue"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
<div id="red"></div>
```

Comment: Kind of. Only the blue and red divs being the ful width of the page, so you cannot see the green div from the left and right sides.

Comment: @Becky Updated my answer

Comment: @Becky After a quick look it appears your `header` need `position: relative`, now it has `static` using an inline style ... I think it is your script that does that, setting it to `static` when scroll up/down

Comment: Thanks! I added `position: relative` to my header css file and then changed `static` to `relative` in my js file. I appreciate your help!